# Carregar var no jquery com dados vindos do BD pelo Controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-5

A `var str` tem *script* com valores fixado. Como faço para que esses valores sejam carregados de um BD através de uma `controller`? Já tenho o método que me trás isso.

```
   var str = "";
    var data = [];

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#btnPesquisarCnpj").click(function () {

            var valor = $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").val();

            if (isCpfCnpj(valor)) {
                return true;

            }
            else {
                $("#txtCnpjPesquisa").focus();

                str += '';
                str += '<label>CNPJ digitado incorretamente!</label>';
                str += '<div>';
                str += '<b><label>Script para Central de Atendimento:</label></b></div>';
                str += '<div><label>Digite novamente o CNPJ, se possível peça que repitam pausadamente.</label>';
                str += '</div>';
                str += '';
                str += '';
                str += '<div>';
                str += '<b>Script para Suporte Técnico:</b></div>';
                str += '<div><label>Digite novamente o CNPJ.</label></div>';

                $('#filtroPesquisa').html(str);

                return false;
            }
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

No seu código não há nenhuma chamada ajax ao servidor para recuperar os dados que você quer. Basicamente, você precisa fazer uma chamada via ajax para o servidor na URL responsável por recuperar esses dados. Isso pode ser feito com jQuery assim

```
var opcoes = {
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    url: 'servidor/caminho-dados'
}

$.ajax(opcoes).then(function (data) {
    // instruções para operar sobre os dados retornados
}).fail(function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    //instruções para lidar com o erro apresentado
});
```

Você pode usar isso no seu código no momento de recuperar os dados e operar sobre eles. Você pode ler mais sobre o uso de ajax com jQuery na própria documentação do jQuery [aqui](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/).